# SQL query that will give me the difference in days between orders given client

Tags: sql

I have a problem with creating a `SQL` query that will give me the difference in days between orders given by client

table

```
id  date       order_no   client_id
1   2016-02-01    1         1
2   2016-02-02    2         2
3   2016-02-03    3         1
4   2016-02-04    4         2
5   2016-02-10    5         1
```

all in all I do not know where to start can have any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) an attempt to solve your problem; and (4) a tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: Why do you have the same information stored in `id` and `order_no`?

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL has the `LAG()` function which does exactly what you want.  So, the following gives you the previous date:

```
SELECT t.*,
       LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY date) as prev_date
FROM t;
```

You can subtract the values, using whatever function is appropriate for your database (often simple subtraction works, but in some databases a special function is required).

In databases that don't support this function, a correlated subquery can do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select client_id, 
       "date" as order_date, 
       order_no,
       lag(date) over (partition by client_id order by "date") - "date" as days_since_last_order
from orders
order by client_id, date, order_no;
```

`DATE` is a keyword in SQL so it needs to be quoted. It's not a good choice for a column name.

`order_no` seems to be the same as `id` - you might want to remove one of those columns.